# What does 'Cheese smells after feet rather than the reverse' mean?

Tags: meaning

I have just encountered a statement, '***Cheese smells after feet rather than the reverse***.'

Does it mean cheese's smell is almost as strong as that of feet? How about 'rather than reverse'?

So the stronger smell comes from feet than from cheese, right?

Comment: *Cheese smells **after** feet* makes no sense at all. (Nor does *feet smell **after** cheese*.) While the main point of the question can be answered, the actual syntax of the phrase is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard this expression, but it seems clear to me that the meaning is "Cheese smells like feet, not the reverse." In other words feet are the primary source of that smell, and the cheese is merely imitating the smell of feet. It sounds like the point of that expression is that you shouldn't say "Phew, your feet smell like cheese," because it is the cheese which smells like your feet.

(In reality, I'm pretty sure it's molds and other microorganisms that cause the smell, and they live on both cheese and feet, but that's beside the point of course.)

It's similar to how you might say "*West Side Story* has taken the plot from *Romeo and Juliet*, not the reverse." since *Romeo and Juliet* came first.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the smell of stinky feet is associated with that of [cheese](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-foot-smell-of-cheese).
It's actually the bacteria/fungi that is breaking down the skin and creates the odor similar to that of cheese (which is fermented milk, hence the smell).

The writer here might hate cheese, so he is saying that it's the cheese actually that smells like stinky feet (he is trying to explain that cheese is gross, comparing it to stinky feet) rather than the other way around.

So in short, he is saying that **stinky feet don't smell like cheese, cheese smell like stinky feet**.